# Is it possible to change the query resultset?

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP code iterates a big MySQL table using PDO and an unbuffered connection: `SELECT ID,X,Y FROM tbl WHERE Z IS NULL`.
For every row, it updates a field Z with the result of `op(X,Y)`. Only rows where Z is unvalued are processed. The update is performed through a separate db connection, with the following query: `UPDATE tbl SET Z=? WHERE X=? AND Y=?`. Same (X,Y) have same Z value, so I found updating multiple rows faster than updating the current row only (it would be `UPDATE tbl SET Z=? WHERE ID=?`). Z is calculated by PHP calling external web service, so I couldn't rewrite it as stored procedure using cursors. I'd like the unbuffered query to be sensitive to changes, so the next row returned isn't a row already processed (Z valued). Lowering isolation levels or inserting Z in a new table, joined to `tbl` in the select query, didn't help.

There is a way to do that?

This was my PHP code:

```
$stmt = $db_unbuf->prepare('SELECT id,x,y,z FROM tbl WHERE z IS NULL');
$stmt->execute();
while($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $z = op($r->x, $r->y);
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE tbl SET z=? WHERE x=? AND y=?');
    $stmt2->execute([$z,$x,$y]);
};
```

I managed to achieve the desired result in two ways:

1- redoing the query with LIMIT 0,1 after every UPDATE:

```
$stmt = $db_unbuf->prepare('SELECT id,x,y,z FROM tbl WHERE z IS NULL LIMIT 0,1');
$stmt->execute();
while($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $z = op($r->x, $r->y);
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE tbl SET z=? WHERE x=? AND y=?');
    $stmt2->execute([$z,$x,$y]);
    $stmt->execute(); // added
};
```

2- using GROUP BY (or SELECT DISTINCT)

```
$stmt = $db_unbuf->prepare('SELECT id,x,y,z FROM tbl WHERE z IS NULL GROUP BY X,Y');
$stmt->execute();
while($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $z = op($r->x, $r->y);
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE tbl SET z=? WHERE x=? AND y=?');
    $stmt2->execute([$z,$x,$y]);
};
```

Comment: Obviously, no. The query is unbuffered only in the PHP side, but the resultset on the database side is already done. Isolation levels have nothing to do with it.

Comment: This is an XY problem and this question must be closed.

Comment: "separate db connection" -- Why separate?

Comment: "WHERE Z IS NULL" -- I don't see that in your code.

Comment: "unbuffered" -- Why?

Comment: Is this a "queue"?  Or "worker" model?

Comment: Yes, this is a queue-like table. I’m using separate DB connection because you cannot do another query on unbuffered connection while already iterating the resultset. Using unbuffered because the resultset is 20GB and growing

Comment: Are you fetching all  20GB each time?  What about "remembering where you left off"?  Or using some kind of INDEX to help narrow down to less than 20GB?

Comment: Now that there is a `WHERE z IS NULL`, why `SELECT z`; it is obviously `NULL`?

Comment: code is just an example to explain the concept, btw fixed ^^

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to XY problem, interesting, I never heard about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized almost immediately that isolation levels are useful only when you have many queries in the same transaction, not when you have a single query, even if unbuffered.

I accomplished the task with a SELECT DISTINCT to read unique items from my queue-like table, then updating all occurrences with an UPDATE .. WHERE, with proper indexes and no performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

what I would do:

create table temptable as (
ID,
z columnz)

insert the record using your modified query and the web server, then only update the original table all at once at the end using the following logic:

update originaltable o 
set z=(select z from temptable t where o.ID=t.ID)
where Z is null and exists (select z from temptable t where o.ID=t.ID);

drop table temptable;

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. **Why** would you do it this way?

Comment: It would work but in my case the loop is a long process (days) so I would be better to use a real table, to avoid starting from beginning if the prices crashes or is interrupted. Though, I would prefer a method not involving extra table

Comment: Because the information available (highlighted before me that a table would be nice) limits brainstorming. :) Even the person asked states (rightfully) that all at once update is the fastest. If you collect the updates (based on external dependency) into a temp file, it can be used for one time bulk update. This is the most effective way I can think of.
Especially as I know SQL but not so familiar with PHP. :)
Btw, a temp table is not 4 fun, but don't forget the strong dependency on the external system providing the Z value. It needs to be cached somehow and array is not SQL option.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score -1):

> so the next row returned isn't a row already processed

Simple:

```
UPDATE ... WHERE ...
    AND z IS NULL
```

Add that clause on to verify that at the time of the update z is still NULL.